# Multiple "root" queries found

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Tried to renaming queries still facing same problem. tried every possible way cleaning cache, commenting queries.

Both queries are in different files and having issue in both.

//doc.js

```
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import BreadcrumbExample from '../components/Breadcrumb'

export const docPageQuery = graphql`
  query DocPageQuery($id: String!) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      fields {
        pageType
        title
        editLink
      }
      tableOfContents
    }
  }
`

function DocTemplate({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <BreadcrumbExample />
      {children}
    </>
  )
}

export default DocTemplate
```

//page.js

```
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query docPageQueryAndDocPageQuery($id: String!) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      fields {
        pageType
        title
      }
    }
  }
`

function PageTemplate({ children }) {
  return children
}

export default PageTemplate
```

[image: gatsby error]